# Calling super().__init__() on subclass of ForceElement causes No constructor defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybind11, drake

I am trying to create a custom `ForceElement` as follows

```
class FrontWheelForce(ForceElement):
    def __init__(self, plant):
        front_wheel = plant.GetBodyByName("front_wheel")
        front_wheel_node_index = front_wheel.index()
        pdb.set_trace()
        ForceElement.__init__(self, front_wheel.model_instance())
```

But get the following error on the line `ForceElement.__init__(self, front_wheel.model_instance())`

```
TypeError: FrontWheelForce: No constructor defined!
```

Comment: The error message suggests the `ForceElement` class does not support subclassing. That is, the python bindings for drake do not wrap the `__init__` method for this class - so presumably `ForceElement.__init__` will raise an AttributeError.

Comment: Judging from the [ForceElement binding](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/multibody/tree_py.cc#L300), it does seem that it's missing the `init` binding

Comment: Yup, and there's actually one more part: (1) As you mentioned, no `py::init()` is defined, but also (2) this is not written as a trampoline class, which is necessary for `pybind11` to permit Python-subclassing of a bound C++ class: [pybind11 docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#overriding-virtual-functions-in-python). Can I ask your use case? I'd be happy to file a Drake issue for you to expose both the base class ctor as well as the trampoline methods. EDIT: Der, reading the code is a good enough use case :P Will file it now.

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12251

Comment: @EricCousineau I was planning to create 2 custom `ForceElement`s.  One is to implement the the resultant force of an actuated wheel acting on a wall (simplified as just a force acting on the center of the wheel that is a function of the torque on the wheel), the other is for the bilateral position constraint, related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559987/constraint-force-for-closed-loop-multibodyplant?noredirect=1#comment103483020_58559987).

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, I am trying to model a robot arm connected to the ground, pushing a wheel against a vertical wall (also connected to the ground).  For that, I would need a position constraint (to ensure the wheel does not penetrate nor leave the wall) and also a force representing the force generated when a torque is applied on the wheel to make it travel up the wall.

Comment: Hm... Looking at the current API for `ForceElement`, it looks like it's heavily dependent on quite a few internal classes, e.g. `MultibodyTree`, `PositionKinematicsCache`, and `VelocityKinematicsCache`... This really complicates the binding process, as I'd prefer not to expose internal elements. That being said, is it possible for you to spike-test the force element you'd want in C++, and then bind it in Python? (Sorry to ask this of you :( )

Comment: @EricCousineau thanks for the response and assistance so far!  According to other's opinion, perhaps `ForceElement` isn't exactly what I should be looking at for my problem.  I'll update this post / the linked post if I happen to end up using `ForceElement` later on.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing a few comments into the correct answer

By ekhumoro

> The error message suggests the `ForceElement` class does not support subclassing. That is, the python bindings for drake do not wrap the `__init__` method for this class - so presumably `ForceElement.__init__` will raise an `AttributeError`.

By Eric Cousineau

> this (ForceElement) is not written as a trampoline class, which is necessary for pybind11 to permit Python-subclassing of a bound C++ class

Ref:
[pybind11 docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#overriding-virtual-functions-in-python), [`ForceElement`binding](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/multibody/tree_py.cc#L300)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the parent's definition.

I'm a little surprised you didn't see this diagnostic:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

I imagine the framework you're using raises "no constructor"
as a reminder that you have some more code to implement
before using that parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the docs [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/040b2b0f7975ac7e78169e149dd9d4c4d9dc7bf7/multibody/tree/force_element.h#L20) for `ForceElement`; "ForceElement allows modeling state and time dependent forces in a MultibodyTree model". That is, a force element that is a function of the torque on the wheel can not be modeled as a `ForceElement`. I believe that what you want is a `FrontWheelSystem`, being a `LeafSystem`, that output the force you want to model. You can apply the external force of your model to the plant through either actuators 
 connected to `get_actuation_input_port()`, or as externally applied spatial forces connected to `get_applied_spatial_force_input_port()`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're suggesting that I split my system into 2 parts, one is the arm and "vertical slider" (where the slider acts as my simplified wheel-wall contact), and the other is this `FrontWheelSystem` that handles the conversion from wheel torque to horizontal force that can then be fed to the arm + slider system.  I'll look into that direction, thanks!

Comment: But regarding the first use case of `ForceElement` (i.e. as a constraint force for a closed loop system), is that still a sensible choice?